# VB.NET: System.Speech gives System.PlatformNotSupportedException

Tags: vb.net, windows-8, speech-recognition

I am trying to get speech recognition going on VB.NET.

There's no errors in the code, but when i test my program i get:

**An unhandled exception of type 'System.PlatformNotSupportedException' occurred in System.Speech.dll**

Additional information: **No recognizer is installed.**

I am on a Dutch device. Does this matter, and when it does, can I set Speech Recognition to English?

Running Windows 8 Pro.

P.S. *going into my control panel/speech recognition tells me Speech Recognition is not supported for your screen language.*

Comment: It doesn't talk Dutch yet.  De machine kan het niet begrijpen.  End of story.  Post to superuser.com to find out how to switch to English.

Comment: @HansPassant Do you know how to switch **only the speech recognition** to English? _Weet je hoe je alleen de spraakherkenning naar Engels overschakelt?_

Comment: The SpeechRecognitionEngine class has a constructor that takes a CultureInfo that specifies the locale.  Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, I have. Still won't launch.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing inproc recognition and do not need a dictation grammar, you might try the server recognizer that comes in the Microsoft Speech Platform. For the SDK and downloads, see:

1. Language packs -
   http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27224
2. Runtime engine -
   http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27225
3. SDK -
   http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27226

The language packs include a recongizer and TTS voice that I believe are Dutch:

1. MSSpeech_TTS_nl-NL_Hanna.msi
2. MSSpeech_SR_nl-NL_TELE.msi

Comment: I've tried this, it leaves me with errors:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Dashboard Voice.exe

Additional information: An error occurred when creating the form. See Exception InnerException for details. The error is: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I've tried everything, but I can't seem to get this error out of the way.

Comment: you might want to show some code. what object reference caused the exception?